# Setting up Spring Cloud Data Flow on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

Do I need to install an instance of Spring Cloud Data Flow on the master server myself, or is this getting installed "automatically" as part of the deployment?

This isn't quite clear from the description at 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_deploying_streams_on_kubernetes

I've followed the guide, though removed every config for MySQL. Maybe this is required. Though I'm somewhat stuck since it's just not assigning an external IP and I do not see why, how to debug, and whether I missed to install some required component.

Edit:
To clarify, I see a scdf service entry when I run

```
kubectl get svc
```

But this service never gets an external IP.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to install an instance of Spring Cloud Data Flow on the master server myself, or is this getting installed "automatically" as part of the deployment?

Spring Cloud Data Flow server needs to be setup either outside (that knows how to connect to the kubernetes environment) or you can use the Spring Cloud Data Flow server docker image to run inside the kubernetes while the latter approach is better.

Step 6 in the link you posted above runs the SCDF docker image inside the kubernetes cluster:

```

Deploy the Spring Cloud Data Flow Server for Kubernetes using the Docker image and the configuration settings you just modified.

$ kubectl create -f src/etc/kubernetes/scdf-config-kafka.yml

$ kubectl create -f src/etc/kubernetes/scdf-secrets.yml

$ kubectl create -f src/etc/kubernetes/scdf-service.yml

$ kubectl create -f src/etc/kubernetes/scdf-controller.yml

```

Comment: I was following this instruction previously, and can see an scdf entry in the service list. Though it doesn't get an external ip assigned (it was unclear to me whether this means data flow is not "installed" or misconfigured and not able to start).

Comment: ok, Can you check if you have `spec.type` points to `LoadBalancer` as this would provide external IP I believe.

Answer (score 0):

MySql is required, that's why it's in the steps.

> Spring Cloud Data Flow uses an RDBMS instead of Redis for stream/task
>   definitions, application registration, and for job repositories.

You can also use any of the other [supported RDMBSes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_rdbms).

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using Helm Charts.

> https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/

- At first install Helm
- Then install Spring Cloud Data Flow

> helm install --name my-release stable/spring-cloud-data-flow

It will install and config relevant pods such as spring-cloud-dataflow-server, mysql, skipper, rabbitmq, etc.

Also you can customize versions and configurations.